# second parameter type depends on first param in typescript

Tags: typescript

Ok so I need some advanced typescript type tricks. I have a function that take 2 parameters, but I want the second parameter type to depends on the first parameter type. For exemple if my first parameter is a number, that my second param need to be a string, but if my first parameter is Record, that my second param be a number. I know I could do some function prototype overloading, but I want this to be dynamic, so It would look like something like this:

```js
type Test = [number, string] | [Record<string, any>, number];

foo<Test>(34, "bar") // ok
foo<Test>({a:34}, 56) // ok
foo<Test>(34, 56) // error
foo<Test>({a:34}, "bar") // error
```

I don't have the advanced knowledge in typescript to figure it out on my own, so I come to all of you guys to guide me, if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to use [tuple types for rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), including [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such tuples.  So you can declare `foo()` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function like this:

```
declare function foo<T extends readonly any[]>(...args: T): void;
```

which would cause your example to behave exactly as shown when you specify `Test` as the `T` parameter:

```
foo<Test>(34, "bar") // ok
foo<Test>({ a: 34 }, 56) // ok
foo<Test>(34, 56) // error
foo<Test>({ a: 34 }, "bar") // error
```

If you don't need `foo()` to be generic then you can hardcode the `Test` rest tuple parameter:

```
declare function bar(...args: Test): void;
bar(34, "bar") // ok
bar({ a: 34 }, 56) // ok
bar(34, 56) // error
bar({ a: 34 }, "bar") // error
```

Either way will work.  TypeScript treats unions-of-rest-tuples as similar to [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), and even the quickinfo in IntelliSense will display them as overloads:

```
bar(/* hints */)
// 1/2 bar(args_0: number, args_1: string): void
// 2/2 bar(args_0: Record<string, any>, args_1: number): void
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG0B2BXAtgIwgCcAaKRQgSwwHMBdKAH3QCUIBjAe0IBMAecqtVIBDDCAB8pbPiK0A3ACgF3dgBthhaADMsGNsAocMULRw68YUCAA9gEDN3hRNw7kdUgookGlriAFAB0wRrU8ABcsACUkQBuHBTciqbmcIgBAMwALKQARHgauVFQAPQlUBwA1gopFgjAAQDeXpHZUAC+pACsAGzFZRXVtWkN-tndfaXlRIRcNWZ16f7Nwq1ZHXkFhEVTVoSzhEoqbOqaJrr6hsZbQSGEYZEjMVDxiYo341D5hf3lVQo3FZrDZQXq-QYAjRjHKgyYDGZzQEtKBtTpfLY7eH7OYKAY3EoAKigAAsqMAnASSlFceUAIwlABMUBuoXgAH0AAyRaQEEhee7s2mRAQ0Z6vbg0qAMxnMqGszmRVicHj8YCUGgiMSSflhNlCqA8ohihLcIA)

Comment: is there a way to dynamically access the second type? because this way I can't do something like
```declare foo<T extends any[]>(a: T[0], b: someClass<T[1]>): void;```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for... is it something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXkj1W)?  If not, could you elaborate, preferably with a [mcve] showing use cases of what to accept/reject?

Answer (score 2):

You can define the first parameter to be generic type `T` which extends `number | Record<string, any>` and then second parameter type to conditionally depend on type `T`:

```
function foo<T extends number | Record<string, any>>(
  x: T, y: T extends number ? string : number) {
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBZJcWCoCjwLzJeDwAA8OAhqwUPGEnHYiGkP1AAB9QE9IAgyNxmYJUJROMxLpw8AA+JUAClW+W8-DwmrZa053G5vP5OIA-NcZaNQJqeXyfgBKUAAb0UAF9KUzVQBmAAs-AARNJHP7HSp4LNGfBVU6GPlfa7+ABWABsobA4cUke9ftAKbTELIbDImc9MbjPoToEDwfzPyLxRwDQ8ZC8iHgAwYIPYNG+bjMzHYDGYkH4sGg6kSnfgehEXn9AFFVgxEDV9P6kjj-eAHKgAOTCABykAk-qCKgA8t8yLtBCOtJBjqhHApXNI8KAnG2dFbvrf0YgYWEK5ewkdtohEAwOBxboWDYLhuCCEogA)

Comment: yeah this would work, but I need it to be dynamic, this need to be hardcoded, wich is not something I want.